# change USBHID example for Isochronous transfer

Tags: c, arm, usb, data-transfer, lpc

I'm new to ARM and I work with LPC1768

I changed the Keil USBHID example and I could send 64 bytes about each 1 ms.
but when I change for more byte the PC don't recognize the USB. I know it's because I'm in the Control transfer but when I try to change the example for Isochronous transfer and send more bytes for example 512 bytes I can't (according to user manual up to 1023 bytes is possible)

I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Look for USB audio example code. It should use isochronous transfers for the audio data.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your response Turbo...Do you know which changes need for transfer 512 integer bytes instead of audio...sorry but I'm new in the ARM and USB

Comment: BTW: For maximum throughput you want to use bulk transfers. Requires drivers like LibUsb/Winusb on the PC side. If you don't need high throughput just put your data into multiple packets.

Comment: I really thankful for your helpful responses...but I think in the Isochronous transfer we can send up to 1023 bytes each 1ms but in the bulk transfer we can just send up to 64 bytes same with control transfer... if I wrong please correct me....and another thing I don't know how can I put my data into multiple packets (endpoints)..which changes is needed...

Comment: and another thing I use LibUsb in C# on the PC side...if I use Isochronous transfer I can't read my data!?...

Comment: Bulk transfers can send *much* more than 64 byte in one millisecond. I have achieved ~1MByte/sec on LPC1768 with bulk transfer (USB mass storage).

Comment: really?!.. didn't you have any problem in the PC side?...so I want to change the USBHID example for  bulk transfer and reach this speed...
I really thankful Turbo...I would be so thankful if you help me for this purpose ...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's better to use bulk transfer as mentioned in comments.. which changes is need for bulk transfer in keil USBHID example and reach the 1Mbyte/s speed?